# ListView in fragment not refreshed when move between fragment

Tags: java, listview, android-fragments, google-cloud-firestore

ListView in `FragmentA` refresh perfectly when move from Activity to Fragment. This is my very very successful code in `fragmentA` but before, this is the OUTPUT that i will show the code after this:

**OUTPUT:**
*from first Query*

```
EAT
DRINK
POOP
```

*from second Query*

```
DONALD TRUMP
BARRACK OBAMA
GEORGE BUSH
```

the success above output happen when i move from,

**FragmentA** --> **Activity** --> back to **FragmentA**

bu when i move like this,

**FragmentA** --> **FragmentB** --> back to **FragmentA**

`ListView` show unwanted ASCENDING result

```
// wrong
POOP
DRINK
EAT

// true
EAT
DRINK
EAT
```

and there is no second query at all.

I am very thankful for your response. Before i show the code after this,
this is what happen why go to Activity then having successful refresh
because i put Fragments in MainActivity, so:

**MainActiviy**  --> **Activity** --> call again onCreate in MainActivity
**FragmentA** --> **FragmentB** --> not call onCreate in MainActivity

All codes below inside FragmentA.

Ok, First Query code:

```
// when scroll reach bottom   
recyclerSeen.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
  @Override
  public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);    

       // vertical scroll
       Boolean reachBottom = !recyclerView.canScrollVertically(-1);


       if (reachBottom) {
          secondQuery();
       }
  }
});


                Query firstQuery = firebaseFirestore
                        .collection("Posts")                        
                        .orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                        .limit(3);    
                                firstQuery.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                        if (isFirstPageFirstLoad) {
                            lastVisible = documentSnapshots.getDocuments().get(documentSnapshots.size() - 1);
                        }

                        for (DocumentChange doc : documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {

                            if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {

                                //String postId = doc.getDocument().getId();
                                ContentProfile contentSeen = doc.getDocument().toObject(ContentProfile.class);

                                /* how to store multi ArrayList */

                                if (isFirstPageFirstLoad) {
                                    contentList.add(contentSeen);
                                } else {
                                    contentList.add(0, contentSeen);
                                }

                                adapterSeen.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }

                        isFirstPageFirstLoad = false;
                    }
                });
```

second Query code:

```
    public void loadMorePost() {       

        Query nextQuery = firebaseFirestore                    
                .orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                .collection("Posts") 
                .startAfter(lastVisible)
                .limit(3);

        nextQuery.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                if (!documentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {

                    lastVisible = documentSnapshots.getDocuments().get(documentSnapshots.size() - 1);
                    for (DocumentChange doc : documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {

                        if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {

                            //String postId = doc.getDocument().getId();
                            ContentProfile contentSeen = doc.getDocument().toObject(ContentProfile.class);
                            contentList.add(contentSeen);

                            adapterSeen.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private HomeFragment homeFragment;
    private Search search;
    private CenterFragment centerFragment;
    private Notification notification;
    private ProfileFragment profileFragment;
    private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        search = new Search();
        centerFragment = new CenterFragment();
        notification = new Notification();
        profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();

        bottomNavigation = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        BottomNavigationViewHelper.removeShiftAnimation(bottomNavigation);

        //initializeFragment
        replaceFragment(homeFragment);   


    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item){

                switch(item.getItemId()){

                    case R.id.action_home :
                        replaceFragment(homeFragment);
                        return true;

                    case R.id.action_search :
                        replaceFragment(search);
                        return true;

                    case R.id.action_center :
                        replaceFragment(centerFragment);
                        return true;

                    case R.id.action_notif :
                        replaceFragment(notification);
                        return true;

                    case R.id.action_profile :
                        replaceFragment(profileFragment);
                        return true;

                    default:
                        return false;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment){
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }


   }
```

i have a solution for handling my above problem, forawhile i don't know how to to refresh it, or call MainActivity `onCreate()` manually , or `remove()` fragment or `whatever` clean code, what i do is, change `replace` become `hide`. And this code below work like a charm, i don't have to refresh my list.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private HomeFragment homeFragment;
    private Search search;
    private CenterFragment centerFragment;
    private Notification notification;
    private ProfileFragment profileFragment;
    private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        search = new Search();
        centerFragment = new CenterFragment();
        notification = new Notification();
        profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();

        bottomNavigation = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        BottomNavigationViewHelper.removeShiftAnimation(bottomNavigation);

        initializeFragment();

        //replaceFragment(homeFragment);

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "MainActivity : onCreate() ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();


        bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item){

                Fragment currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.main_container);

                switch(item.getItemId()){

                    case R.id.action_home :
                        replaceFragment(homeFragment, currentFragment);
                        return true;

                    case R.id.action_search :
                        replaceFragment(search, currentFragment);
                        return true;

                    case R.id.action_center :
                        replaceFragment(centerFragment, currentFragment);
                        return true;

                    case R.id.action_notif :
                        replaceFragment(notification, currentFragment);
                        return true;

                    case R.id.action_profile :
                        replaceFragment(profileFragment, currentFragment);
                        return true;

                    default:
                        return false;
                }
            }
        });
    }

     private void initializeFragment(){

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_container, homeFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_container, search);
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_container, centerFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_container, notification);
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_container, profileFragment);

        fragmentTransaction.hide(search);
        fragmentTransaction.hide(centerFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.hide(notification);
        fragmentTransaction.hide(profileFragment);

        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }

//    private void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment){
//        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
//
//        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, fragment);
//        fragmentTransaction.commit();
//    }


    private void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, Fragment currentFragment){

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if(fragment == homeFragment){

            fragmentTransaction.hide(search);
            fragmentTransaction.hide(centerFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.hide(notification);
            fragmentTransaction.hide(profileFragment);

        }

        if(fragment == search){

            fragmentTransaction.hide(homeFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.hide(centerFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.hide(notification);
            fragmentTransaction.hide(profileFragment);

        }

        if(fragment == centerFragment){

            fragmentTransaction.hide(search);
            fragmentTransaction.hide(homeFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.hide(notification);
            fragmentTransaction.hide(profileFragment);

        }

        if(fragment == notification){

            fragmentTransaction.hide(search);
            fragmentTransaction.hide(centerFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.hide(homeFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.hide(profileFragment);

        }

        if(fragment == profileFragment){

            fragmentTransaction.hide(search);
            fragmentTransaction.hide(centerFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.hide(notification);
            fragmentTransaction.hide(homeFragment);

        }

        fragmentTransaction.show(fragment);

        //fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }
```

Comment: The fragments are created in the `MainActivity` and data is not refreshed because these fragments are not refreshed new data in `onResume` method.

Comment: @LiemVo yess, ..where is `onResume` do you mean? because `onResume` in fragments not working at all and if you mean `onResume` in `MainActivity` what should i refresh? because actually the data list inside fragments, what should i refresh in `MainActivity` onResume?

Comment: I mean the `onResume` in the fragment.

Comment: i've tried, not working, but i am not sure why @LiemVo